# Access a Resource declare in a Resource Dictionary referenced in App.xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, dictionary, uwp

I have a resource dictionary - Styles\StyleDic1, this has a Flyout as one of it's resources

I included it in my App.xaml file like so:

```
<Application
    ...
    ...>
<Application.Resources>
    ...

    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\StyleDictionary1.xaml" x:Key="StyleDic1"/>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I have another file TimeTC.xaml with an AppBarButton and i wanted to use the flyout resource on it, so it tried this

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Edit" Label="Edit" ... Flyout="{StaticResource ResourceKey=EditFlyout}"/>
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Here are the full contents of App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="SabinusUWP.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SabinusUWP"
    RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Application.Resources>
        <x:Int32 x:Key="TimeFormat">24</x:Int32>
        <Color x:Key="grayish">#99CBCBCB</Color>
        <Color x:Key="deepgray">#99AAAAAA</Color>
        <Color x:Key="black">#FF000000</Color>
        <Color x:Key="sleepblack">#FF414141</Color>
        <Color x:Key="bluegray">#FFE3F3F2</Color>
        <Color x:Key="transparent">#00E3F3F2</Color>
        <Color x:Key="green">#CC2B9B2B</Color>
        <Color x:Key="hoverGreen">#CC3BC53B</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarBtnFBrush"  Color="{StaticResource black}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarBBrush"  Color="{StaticResource grayish}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FolderPressedBrush"  Color="{StaticResource deepgray}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridBBrush"  Color="{StaticResource transparent}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TimeTHeadBtn"  Color="{StaticResource transparent}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TimeTBodyBtn"  Color="{StaticResource green}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TimeTBodyHoverBtn"  Color="{StaticResource hoverGreen}"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="TimeTBodySleepBtn" x:Key="TimeTBodySleepBtn"  Color="{StaticResource sleepblack}"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\StyleDictionary1.xaml" x:Key="StyleDic1"/>

</Application.Resources>
```

And here is StyleDictionary1.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SabinusUWP.Styles">

    <!--Bottom Appbar EditFlyout -->

    <Flyout x:Name="EditFlyout" x:Key="EditFlyout"
            Placement="Bottom">
        <Grid Background="White"
              Height="150"
              Width="100"
              CanDrag="True">
            <StackPanel Background="White"
                        x:Name="panel"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        Height="150"
                        Width="100">
                <Button Content="12 hour"
                        Click="_12hour"
                        Height="50"
                        Width="100"
                        Background="{StaticResource AppBarBBrush}" />
                <Button Content="24 hour"
                        Click="_24hour"
                        Height="50"
                        Width="100"
                        Background="{StaticResource AppBarBBrush}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Flyout>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Sorry if i didn't pass the info correctly, the second file (TimeTC.xaml) isn't a resource dictionary, its a page.

Comment: Could you please post the *full* contents of the <Application.Resources> element in your App.xaml.cs file and also the contents of Styles\StyleDic1.xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you can't have a resource dictionary in a resource dictionary, you need to merge them together into a single dictionary

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="View/Templates.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="View/Images.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add merged dictinory to add N number of styles to your application

Example code :

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="App_OnStartup"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```